# Undefined variable: (2/2) ErrorException en una Vista.

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy tratando de importar una vista a un archivo en formato pdf y me lanza que no tengo definida la variable. Estoy usando **laravel-dompdf** y las migraciones estan en `MySQL`.

Tengo este error:

> (2/2) ErrorException
>
> Undefined variable: cartItems (View: /var/www/html/meso/resources/views/cart/index.blade.php)

`PDFController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use PDF;

class PDFController extends Controller
{
    public function pdf(Request $request){
    $products=Product::all();
    view()->share('products', $products);
    if ($request->has('descargar')) {

$pdf = PDF::loadView('cart.index');
        return $pdf->download('cotizacion');
    }
return view('cart.index');
}
}
```

Mi ruta en mi archivo `web`

```
Route::get('/pdf', 'PDFController@pdf')->name('pdf');
```

Mi controllador en donde llama a la vista que deseo importar:

```
CartController
```

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
public function index()
{
    $cartItems=Cart::content();
    return view('cart.index',compact('cartItems'));
}
```

Esta es la vista `cart/index.blade.php` y es donde llamo a mi ruta en un button al final del codigo:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Cart Items</h3>


    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>qty</th>
            <th>size</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($cartItems as $cartItem)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$cartItem->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$cartItem->price}}</td>
                <td width="50px">
                    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['cart.update',$cartItem->rowId], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
                    <input name="qty" type="text" value="{{$cartItem->qty}}">


                </td>
                <td>
                    <div > {!! Form::select('size', ['small'=>'Small','medium'=>'Medium','large'=>'Large'] , $cartItem->options->has('size')?$cartItem->options->size:'' ) !!}
                       </div>

                </td>

                <td>
                    <input style="float: left"  type="submit" class="button success small" value="Ok">
                    {!! Form::close() !!}

                    <form action="{{route('cart.destroy',$cartItem->rowId)}}"  method="POST">
                       {{csrf_field()}}
                       {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                       <input class="button small alert" type="submit" value="Delete">
                     </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                Tax: ${{Cart::tax()}} <br>
                Sub Total: $ {{Cart::subtotal()}} <br>
                Grand Total: $ {{Cart::total()}}
            </td>
            <td>Items: {{Cart::count()}}

            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="{{route('checkout.shipping')}}" class="button">Checkout</a>
    <a href="{{route('pdf')}}" class="button small alert">Import to PDF</a>
</div>



@endsection
```

Comment: Intenta cambiarle el nombre a la variable que pasas a la vista, o pasala como un arreglo sin usar compact para que puedes ir comprobando otras opciones. Aunque por lo que vi no aprecio un error.

Comment: ¿qué arroja un `dump($cartItems)` en el controlador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si en la vista `cart/index.blade.php` no vas a pasar más variables llama el facade **Cart** desde la vista y cambia:

`@foreach($cartItems as $cartItem)` por `@foreach(Cart::content() as $cartItem)`

**Editado: Segunda Parte**

Yo lo hago así y funciona normalmente:

```
public function pdf(Request $request) {

    $products = Product::all();

   if ($request->has('descargar')) {

       $pdf = \PDF::loadView('cart.index', ['products' => $products]); 
       return $pdf->download('cotizacion');
   }

   return view('cart.index')->with('products', $products);

}
```

Seria importante ver que resultado o error arroja.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya no me lanza el mismo error, ahora no me genera el pdf. Cuando hago click en el boton no me descarga nada.

Comment: Pasa le la variable a la vista a ver si funciona, prueba lo así:  PDF::loadView('cart.index', $products);

Comment: No, sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta editada